# Typeclasses task Haskell

Tags: haskell

This is the typesigniture.

```
reverse::(foldable t, Applicative t, Monoid (t,a) => t a -> t a)
reverse ls = ____ (\l r -> r \`________\` ______ l) _______ ls
```

and this is my solution

```
reverse::(foldable t, Applicative t, Monoid (t,a) => t a -> t a
reverse ls = foldr (\l r -> r `mappend` pure l) t ls
```

But it doesn't work out, so my question is,

how can I see what to do? I have taken `mappend` because of the monoid,

pure for the applicative and folder because of the foldable.

Would it be a list I would know what to do and put [] into the function.

```
reverse ls = ____ (\l r -> r \`________\` ______ l) **** [] **** ls
```

I just know t so i put a t in it.

```
reverse ls = ____ (\l r -> r \`________\` ______ l) ___*** t ***___ ls
```

So has anyone a solution for this function depending on the given type classes ?

Comment: Hint: you should work with `mempty`.

Comment: Please make sure to always post syntactically correct code. Best copy&paste from a Haskell file that you know has no parse errors into StackOverflow, and then format it as a code block using ctrl+k.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can work with the `mempty` to provide the initial value, this thus means that your function looks like:

```
reverse :: (Foldable t, Applicative t, Monoid (t a)) => t a -> t a
reverse ls = foldr (\l r -> r `mappend` pure l) mempty ls
```

This thus means that `[1,4,2,5]` will be mapped on

```
mempty `mappend` pure 5 `mappend` pure 2 `mappend` pure 4 `mappend` pure 1
```

for lists this thus looks like:

```
[] `mappend` [5] `mappend` [2] `mappend` [4] `mappend` [1]
```

and this is thus equivalent to:

```
[5,2,4,1]
```

You can generalize the signature to:

```
reverse :: (Foldable f, Applicative t, Monoid (t a)) => f a -> t a
reverse = foldr (\l r -> r `mappend` pure l) mempty
```

Here the input type should be a `Foldable` of items `a`, and the output type can be anything `t a` where `t` is an `Applicative` and `t a` a `Monoid` instance.